# Order of optional parameters in initializer

Tags: ruby

Why am I getting the following error

```
a.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
...alize(a = "default val", b, c = [])
a.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input
```

on the following code

```
class A
  attr_reader :a, :b, :c

  def initialize(a = "default val", b, c = [])
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end

  def self.open(a)
    args = {
      b: "2",
      c: [1, 2, 3]
    }.values
    
    A.new(a, *args)
  end
end
```

when trying to call  `a` property

```
a2 = A.open("something")
p a2.a
```

Removing the last default value from initializer `=[]` solves the problem. Reordering the arguments so the parameters with default values go at the end of initialize helps too.

`def initialize(a = "default val", b, c)`

or

`def initialize(b, c=[], a = "default val")` and `A.new(*args, a)` (but I suppose this is wrong)

As I remember there was a rule about ordering of optional params.

Comment: btw, switching to kwargs solves all of these problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define optional parameters before AND after mandatory parameters, in some cases it will be impossible to decide how a goven list or arguments should map to the defined parameters.

In your case, when defining this method:

```
class A
  def initialize(a = "default val", b, c = [])
    #...
  end
end
```

How would you handle this when giving two arguments,. i.e.

```
A.new 'hello', 'world'
```

You could then assign

```
a = 'hello'
b = 'world'
c = []
```

but you could equally set

```
a = 'default val'
b = 'hello'
c = 'world'
```

Given this unambiguity, Ruby rejects those constructs. You thus have to define all optional parameters either at the front or the back of your parameter list, while it is commonly accepted standard to define optional arguments only at the end.

If you want to be more specific about which arguments should be set with a large number of optional parameters, you can also use keyword arguments. Since you have to specify the name of the arguments when calling the method here, the order of mandatory and optional keyword arguments doesn't matter.

Comment: You  may wish to provide an example of the use of keyword parameters in this case, including the retrieval of the values of one or two within the method.